# Python calendar TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to create a calendar and schedule a timeslot for one of the weekdays.

```
timetable = [[""] * 24 for day in range(7)]

timetable[0][15] = "meeting with Jane"

# first let's define weekday names
WEEKDAYS = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
'Saturday', 'Sunday')

# now we iterate over each day in the timetable

for day in timetable:

# and over each timeslot in each day

day_name = WEEKDAYS[day]

  for i, event in enumerate(day):
      if event: # if the slot is not an empty string
        print("%s at %02d:00 -- %s" % (day_name, i, event))
```

I get the error:

```
day_name = WEEKDAYS[day]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not list
```

I understand that 'day' is being passed as a list to tuple which is causing this error but what modifications should i make to my code to resolve this?

Comment: Think about what is _actually_ in `timeable`(_hint_: it's a list of lists). Even if you did iterate through each _nested_ list however, you'd still have a problem. _strings cannot be tuple indices_. I suggest taking a moment and re-thinking the logic of your code. If you are having trouble, have a read over [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/).

Comment: @leaf you are correct. Its a list of lists. I am new to python so not so aware of many things. I think there should be another variable in the outer for loop which could be passed as an index to the tuple but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: See the most recent edit to my above comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use more `enumerate`!

```
for index, day in enumerate(timetable):
    day_name = WEEKDAYS[index]
    for i, event in enumerate(day):
        if event: # if the slot is not an empty string
            print("%s at %02d:00 -- %s" % (day_name, i, event))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `enumerate(day)`, and what are the two values it enumerates over? (I might change `i` to `hour` for readability.) You're doing this to get the index and the value in pairs.

You can do the same with timetable:

```
for day, agenda in enumerate(timetable):
    day_name = WEEKDAYS[day]
    for hour, event in enumerate(agenda):
        …
```